# Reverse triangle inequality for square of euclidean norm?

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

The reverse triangle inequality as listed on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality shows that

$| ||x||_2 - ||y||_2 | \leq ||x -y||_2$ for $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$, where $||x||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$ is the euclidean norm.

Now I wonder if the reverse triangle inequality also holds when using the square of the euclidean norm $||x||_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ instead, i.e. does

$| ||x||_2^2 - ||y||_2^2 | \leq ||x-y||_2^2 $  hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take $x=(1,1), y=(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!